# Obtain source address from route

Tags: c++, linux, boost, routes

In [this users example](https://superuser.com/a/399710/201302) a route is obtained by using the [command line utility ip](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ip) in [linux](/questions/tagged/linux). Example output:

```
$ ip route get 4.2.2.1
4.2.2.1 via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0  src 192.168.0.121 
    cache 
$
```

Let's refer to the addresses in the following manner:

- `4.2.2.1` as address `A` (destination)
- `192.168.0.1` as address `B` (gateway)
- `192.168.0.121` as address `C` (source)

In my case I'm interested in `C` - and I'm trying to figure out how I might be able to obtain the same piece of information in my [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) program. Specifically

- Given address `A`, find address `C`
- do not want to use [system](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) or anything that will somehow run a shell command
- Using [boost](/questions/tagged/boost) is allowed, and preferred

Any recommendations? Thanks

Comment: For what do you need A? C should be the address of eth0. Or is it important for you over which interface you'll be routed?

Comment: @mash Yes, it is important - my machine has multiple interfaces so I'd like to find out which one was used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There you go:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "boost/asio/io_service.hpp"
#include "boost/asio/ip/address.hpp"
#include "boost/asio/ip/udp.hpp"

boost::asio::ip::address source_address(
    const boost::asio::ip::address& ip_address) {
  using boost::asio::ip::udp;
  boost::asio::io_service service;
  udp::socket socket(service);
  udp::endpoint endpoint(ip_address, 0);
  socket.connect(endpoint);
  return socket.local_endpoint().address();
}

// Usage example:
int main() {
  auto destination_address = boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("8.8.8.8");
  std::cout << "Source ip address: "
            << source_address(destination_address).to_string()
            << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Works great. Out of curiosity, why UDP instead of TCP?

Comment: Because you don't need the features TCP offers in this case.

Answer (score 0):

mash's answer is almost right but fails on iOS.  The line `udp::endpoint endpoint(ip_address, 0);` needs to have a non-zero port or you'll get the error "Can't assign requested address" since 0 is not a valid port number.  I don't think it matters what the port is (as long as it's a valid non-zero port number) so I would recommend using 3478 which is the standard UDP STUN port.

Corrected code:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "boost/asio/io_service.hpp"
#include "boost/asio/ip/address.hpp"
#include "boost/asio/ip/udp.hpp"

boost::asio::ip::address source_address(
    const boost::asio::ip::address& ip_address) {
  using boost::asio::ip::udp;
  boost::asio::io_service service;
  udp::socket socket(service);
  udp::endpoint endpoint(ip_address, 3478);
  socket.connect(endpoint);
  return socket.local_endpoint().address();
}

// Usage example:
int main() {
  auto destination_address = boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("8.8.8.8");
  std::cout << "Source ip address: "
            << source_address(destination_address).to_string()
            << '\n';
}
```